# High voltage DC to AC oscillator circuit

Tags: ac, dc, oscillator, inverter, high-voltage

I am trying to design a oscillator circuit that will convert ~10 kV DC at 60 hz to ~9-10 kV AC at 60 hz, and all the information I'm seeing is circuits that step up voltage. I wonder if making this circuit is even possible; if it is I'd like to read into it a bit.

Comment: You should let us know the intended purpose of this device since we may be able to offer alternative solutions. Also, do you have any experience at building and using kilovolt circuits? If not, I would not recommend you pursue this project as these voltages can easily be lethal. In any event you need to provide many more details such as the frequency of the AC voltage, power level, load impedance, etc.

Comment: That will be extremely difficult as semiconductors at that voltage isn’t really available. Wild idea would be a tuned LC tank and spark gap to drive it.

Comment: What frequency and power levels are you looking to support? Is the load resistive, reactive or mixed?

Comment: @winny They are, just not to you and me. I've seen papers and press releases for e.g. 10kV SiC MOSFETs and IGBTs; though I'm still not even sure if they're real products yet, honestly.  I presume they want some serious interest (or contact information, or more) first, perhaps because such devices are on the ITAR list or something, not sure.

Comment: That said, what is your (OP's) interest? If you're doing medium voltage e.g. power distribution design, surely you have enough engineering background to have an idea what's involved. Is this more some amateur toy? Idle curiosity?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've seen them, but OP would need more than 10 kV rating to switch 10 kV DC. OP would be better off finding a different power source, for example an AC outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These converters (both AC->DC and DC->AC) are indeed possible, as is demonstrated by the converters used to connect [HVDC transmission lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current) to the existing HVAC networks.

Most practical circuits are currently built with ["thyristor valves"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVDC_converter#Thyristor_valves) which are stacked thyristor alternatives to the older converters using mercury arc rectifiers and thyratons.

[image]

(Image from Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVDC_converter#Thyristor_valves).)

However, this is not an easy undertaking, and unless you do your research, you are likely to let out a lot of ["magic smoke"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke)!